# HttpPost can't get a value in php

Tags: php, android, http-post

I'm trying to post some values using `HTTP` post, 
but whenever I post my values, I get blank on PHP side.
Is something wrong with my code?

Code:

```
public void postData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //httppost url
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.x.x:80/phptest");

        try {


            // Add data in name-value parilist
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("people[name]", "Shyam"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("people[sex]", "male"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("people[birthyear]", "1999"));


            //http-enity                
            HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8);

                    //setting httppost header and entity
            httppost.addHeader(entity.getContentType());
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  
            if (resEntity != null) {    
                   //print httprespose   
                   Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            }
```

Comment: While posting are the http headers emtpy or not? Check it in chrome devtools for example.

Comment: Can you paste the php code too?

Comment: What does your PHP code do?

Comment: how you get your data in php? you have to get it in php like $_POST['people']

Comment: @tauitdnmd , yes something like that, but point is i'm getting blank on that

Comment: @ramdesh, i need php to make SQL queries

Comment: @PrabinByanjankar can you try to get with $_GET

Comment: finally, got it right, i forgot to place "/" at the end of url

Answer (score 0):

2 points,

why you are using these names for the param? do you really need them to be like this?

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("people[name]", "Shyam"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("people[sex]", "male"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("people[birthyear]", "1999"));
```

they should be `...new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Shyam"));`
or `...new BasicNameValuePair("people_name", "Shyam"));`

second point:
how do you read params at PHP side?
if this is valid param name, and it will work
you have to read them this way: `$_POST["people[name]"]`

and if you use second naming method, it should be `$_POST["name"]`

Comment: yes, i need them like that, i want to pass the whole array.

Comment: finally, echo $people['name']